# Widfly logging configuration with SpringMVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j, wildfly-8

I have a problem with logging and printers management using wildfly AS as its container.

I set up the default basic springMVC application using eclipse tool, the project is set up with default **log4j.xml** file, when i deploy it on wildfly, all the loggers are ignored.

I figured out after some search on google that there musts be a configuration that has to be done on server **standalone.xml** file side.

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>ma.mrer</groupId>
        <artifactId>net</artifactId>
        <name>SpringMVC</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <java-version>1.6</java-version>
            <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
            <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
            <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                     </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- AspectJ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
            </dependency>   

            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- @Inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>        
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

**HomeController.java**

```
    package ma.mrer.net;

    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    /**
     * Handles requests for the application home page.
     */
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

        /**
         * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
            logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

            String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

            model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

            return "home";
        }

    }
```

Guys i hope u can give me a way to solve this issue.

I'm using Wildfly 8.2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using slf4j the `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` should be marked with `<scope>provided</scope>`. The other slf4j and log4j dependencies are not required if you want to use the logging subsystem in WildFly.

If you'd rather use your `log4j.xml` with slf4j then the easiest solution would be to create a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) and exclude the logging subsystem.

Note that if you use a logging configuration file any changes you want to make to your log configuration will require a redeploy of the application. Using the WildFly logging subsystem you can make most changes at runtime without requiring a reload or redeploy.